# mkdir and mount in initramfs

Tags: mount, mkdir, busybox, initramfs

I am writing an *initramfs*, executed in *busybox*, in which I mount a partition using those commands:

```
/bin/busybox mount -n -t proc proc /proc
mount -n -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
mount -n -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -n -t tmpfs inittemp /mnt
mkdir /mnt/saved
mount -n -t "${rootfstype}" -o "${rootflags}" ${device} /mnt/saved
```

But when the system starts up, I have this error:

```
mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p2 on /mnt/saved failed: No such file or directory
```

I know that when the device is not found, there is a message like `Device does not exist`, so I think the problem is coming from the directory `/mnt/saved` that is not correctly created yet.

I tried adding an `ls -l /mnt` after the `mkdir` to check that the directory is correctly created, but most of the time, if I do so, the error disappears. So I though the problem might be synchronization problem (of the *tmpfs*, weird!) So I tried some other things like creating a dummy file in the directory to force a kind of synchronisation. This works, but is a dirty workaround and I want to find the real cause of the problem to build a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time I was writing my question, I finally found the solution by myself… I post it anyway just in case somebody is stuck like me.

Actually, the `mount` command of *busybox* does not show a message about device, if it cannot find it, but always show `No such file or directory`.

My problem was actually coming from the root device which was not ready yet, and so not in the `/dev` directory yet. In order to make it work correctly, I simply added this line before the `mount`:

```
while ${rootwait} && ! [ -b "${device}" ]; do sleep 1; done
```